# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many association with other query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Im using Rails 5 and I wanna doing has_and_belongs_to_many relation with other query. Its instead of merge two queries but its not same. Actually I wanna do this clean way.

```
branches
-----------------------------------
id
name:string
active:boolean
..

course_contents
-----------------------------------
id
title:string
show_all_branches:boolean
active:boolean
..

branches_course_contents
-----------------------------
branch_id
course_content_id


class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :course_contents
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end

class CourseContent < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :show_all_branches, -> { where(show_all_branches: true) }
end
```

How can i do it clean?

```
@branch.course_contents.active + CourseContent.show_all_branches
```

I want to write this sql output with rails. That sql command works fine for me.

```
select *, 
  (select branch_id 
   from branches_course_contents 
   where course_content_id=course_contents.id and branch_id=2) as Sube 
from course_contents 
where 
  (select branch_id
    from branches_course_contents 
    where course_content_id=course_contents.id and branch_id=2)=2 
   or show_all_branches=true) 
  and content_type=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@branch.course_contents.active.merge(CourseContent.show_all_branches)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you show the query from console?

Comment: I updated my question description. That sql command work fine. I want to write that with rails.